# Angular autofocus directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive to give focus on an specific input field of form.
It just fails: element is not focused.
This is the directive code:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('autoFocus', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope : {
      trigger: '@autoFocus'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
        if (value === 'true') {
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log('giving focus to element', element[0].id);
            element[0].focus();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And this is the markup:

```
<form ng-show="signedIn()" class="service form-horizontal">

  ....

  <div class="row" title="Author">
    <div class="col-xs-8>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="service.author" auto-focus="true" placeholder="" ng-disabled="servicePrintMode" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  ....

</form>
```

Any idea of the reason why it doesn't work?
I'd even accept a workaround... :-)

***UPDATE***:
This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/626/): on Chrome it works like a charm, on Firefox (30.0) it does not... :-(

Comment: I think it is actually working. Did you see the behavior in a plunker or jsfiddle? Or your app are opened in iframe?

Comment: App in not in an iframe. I've added a jsfiddle... (sorry for the delay... :-)

Comment: Try open this in firefox http://fiddle.jshell.net/A8Vgk/626/show/ to see if it work when open the app directly witout iframe.

Comment: There is something *really* strange, here: opened outside jsfiddle it always works, but sometimes it works also in the fiddle (I suppose when opening a fresh window or tab...). But, when it starts not working, it doesn't work anymore... However, in my app (standard angular.js app) it doesn't work, and it's *not* in an iframe (as far as I can tel...) :-(

Comment: What I found is in firefox, the input is always in focus. But the visual appearance, the blinking cursor, will appear only if its parent document is active. So the blinking cursor might not appear for the app in iframe because the iframe might be inactive.

Comment: But, if I start typing, text doesn't go to that input...

Comment: Try run `document.activeElement` in console, what does it return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59017/discussion-between-marcos-and-runtarm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   angular.module('myApp').directive('autoFocus', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            scope: {
                trigger: '@autoFocus'
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                scope.$watch('trigger', function (value) {
                    console.log('focus to element ' + element[0].id + " " +value );
                    if (value == 'true') {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            console.log('giving focus to element', element[0].id);
                            element[0].focus();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, `trigger: '@focus'` was just a typo... Corrected, it doesn't work the same way... :-(